# Rails application config access slow - why?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, app-config

We always used to put our application config into the environment files. That's no good for production management, so now we load it through an initializer:

```
# myinitializer.rb
ApplicationConfig = YAML.load_file("#{Rails.root}/config/application/default.yml").symbolize_keys()
```

As soon as we started accessing the configuration through `ApplicationConfig`, application test performance got much worse. One rspec suite dropped from 4 seconds to 30.

In our application controller, we need to take some action using a `before_filter`, which works as follows:

```
before_filter :extra_control

def extra_control
  if ApplicationConfig.some_flag
    ...
  end
end
```

Declaring a variable pointing to `ApplicationConfig` fully restores performance:

```
config = ApplicationConfig

def extra_control
  if config.some_flag
    ...
  end
end
```

Why? Why does accessing this through the global variable destroy performance? We do this throughout the code base in views and other controllers. Do we need to do this differently, e.g. by injecting an instance variable into all controllers?

**Edit:** we did verify that the code loading the configuration from YAML gets called exactly once either way, so repeated loading does not seem to be the root cause.

**Edit:** it turns out that this was a bug caused by a setting variable that was being loaded as a string rather than a boolean, causing the application to go into a test sleep pattern :( Sorry, thanks for trying. 3 days of my life I'll never get back!

Comment: Is it only worse in test environment? Did you check at which stage in your test environment the initialiser is called? You can do so via a debugger or by adding some printing.

Comment: I have no data on whether it's only slow in test, but I do know that the initializer gets called exactly once both in test and in development - so it's not a repeating initializer call slowing it down.

Comment: Also note: the performance slowdown is only when accessing ApplicationConfig directly, it goes away when assigning it to a variable, as shown above.

Comment: Hmm, this doesn't reproduce for me. Did you try profiling your tests? Perhaps something to do with the way they are implemented?

Comment: How big is your config file?

Comment: The config file has about 20 entries. I have also confirmed that it is being read *exactly once*. It is still slower to refer to ApplicationConfig than to assign to a variable and then read, as shown above.

Comment: @xcut with 3k reputation you should know by now that on Stack Exchange sites we want people who ask questions to accept answers, not change the title to include 'RESOLVED'.  If this means you have to write your own answer, that is fine, but please accept an answer to the question. If nothing else, it sets a good example for others.

Comment: @xcut Thank you! Now do something with the bounty.  Since no one solved the problem for you, maybe give it to whoever did the most or best work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The other answers here did not make a difference - this was caused by an unrelated problem. For the record

- Initializers are called exactly once by rspec
- It does not make a difference whether ApplicationConfig or APPLICATION_CONFIG is used
- Assigning to a variable did not make a speed difference either

Answer (score 0):

I can't speak to why your approach is slow, but maybe a different way of handling settings would be worth looking into.  I prefer the idea of having a singleton class that contains config information:

```
class SiteSettings
    def initialize
        @settings = {}
    end

    @@instance = SiteSettings.new

    def set_setting(key, value)
        @settings ||= {}
        @settings[key] = value
    end

    def self.setting(key, value)
        @@instance.set_setting(key, value)
    end

    def settings
        @settings
    end

    def self.method_missing(meth, *args, &block)
        if @@instance.settings.has_key?(meth)
            @@instance.settings[meth]
        else
            super
        end
    end

    setting :test_setting, 'test'
    setting :another_test_setting '.....'
end

puts SiteSettings.test_setting
puts SiteSettings.another_test_setting
```

The [Discourse app](https://github.com/discourse/discourse) takes a similar approach.

- [site_setting.rb](https://github.com/discourse/discourse/blob/master/app/models/site_setting.rb)
- [site_setting_extension.rb](https://github.com/discourse/discourse/blob/master/lib/site_setting_extension.rb)

Comment: Thanks for making the effort - the issue was unrelated in the end. FYI, we load a YAML file and then rush Hashie on it to generate an object, this works very well, with no performance hit.

Answer (score 0):

Try use const:

`APPLICATIONCONFIG = YAML.load(File.read(File.expand_path("#{RAILS_ROOT}/config/application/default.yml", __FILE__)))`

or

`APPLICATIONCONFIG = YAML::load(File.open("#{RAILS_ROOT}/config/application/default.yml"))`

I think its make your file slow because load file but not open/read.

Comment: This did not make any speed difference, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0):

I think it will help to figure out if the YAML file load\read is slow, or YAML parsing is slow. My guess is that ruby is parsing the YAML file every time you call your `ApplicationConfig` variable. Can you try renaming it to `APPLICATION_CONFIG` like so:

```
APPLICATION_CONFIG = YAML.load(File.read(Rails.root.join('config', 'application', 'my_config.yml')))
```

Please do not inject an instance variable in all your controllers :)

Comment: This did not make any speed difference, I'm afraid.